# When I give the php sleep() function a value more than 30; it put the whole script into a loop ( starting from the first line )

Tags: php

In my php script (`index.php`) if I put a `sleep()` function with a value more than 30, it puts the script into a loop (it re-excute the whole script as if I call it again).
I have tried setting `max_excution_time` to more than 30 sec (180,600,even more), but it only rise the limit from 30 (that I mentioned at the title) to 60.
For example:

index.php

```
<?php
//do some thing here e.g send message via telegram bot
sleep(70);
?>
```

this will send the message many times (really a lot of times).

could this be related with my server (I am using 000webhost)? here is the [phpinfo](https://000x.000webhostapp.com/myphpinfo.php).

*I use `'ini_set()'` to set max_excution_time. `set_time_limit()` is disabled in my server.

Comment: You should **never** use `sleep` in PHP, btw - because it's a blocking call that effectively steals a thread from the parent webserver's thread-pool (if running in-proc). If you need to perform asynchronous tasks you shouldn't be using PHP (at least not without `pthreads` baked-in).

Comment: you can use  await async  for such operations, no need sleep

Comment: @dılosürücü Stock PHP does not support `async`/`await`. While HHVM and some other implementations do, they are not standard PHP environments. I'd wager far more PHP users have `pthreads` than have async/await - and even _that_'s non-standard and probably still amounts to a tiny minority of users.